# why we need connetion-time-out management

Tags: c++, c, epoll, libevent

to me，the connection will all the time be readable，or it will be writeable.

cant we rely on the r/w event? 
when client close connection,r/w will get error return sooner or later,then we can close fds.

so the only meaning of connection management is to prevent a connection from doing nothing(it may all the time be writable to the sever,but server got nothin to write after Normal interaction),is this right?

Comment: "to me，the connection will all the time be readable，or it will be writeable." - Well, it won't be to your computer, so the question is; which perspective matters more?

Answer (score 1):

> to me，the connection will all the time be readable，or it will be writeable

No it won't. It will only be readable when there is data already present in the socket receive buffer, and it will only be writable when there is room in the socket send buffer (which is most of the time, but not all of it).

That's what `select()` is *for:* to tell you when these events occur.

> can't we rely on the r/w event?

If this means 'read-write' event, that's what `select()` gives you. If you mean something else you will have to explain what.

> when client close connection, r/w will get error return sooner or later

No it won't. It will get an end of stream indication. This takes several forms depending on what API and language you're using, but none of them is an error.

> then we can close fds.

Certainly you should close `fd`s when you're finished with them, but there's a bit more to network programming than that.

> so the only meaning of connection management is to prevent a connection from doing nothing (it may all the time be writable to the sever,but server got nothin to write after Normal interaction),is this right?

It is meaningless. You've introduced the term 'connection management' without a source or citation and then asserting it only has the meaning you ascribe to it, without proof, and the word 'so' is just a *non sequitur.*

Comment: It will only be readable when there is data already present in the socket receive buffer, and it will only be writable when there is room in the socket send buffer (which is most of the time, but not all of it).——seems that a connection may be readable and writables at the same time?thx